# Django db_index=True not create index after migration

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-migrations, mysql-5.6

I have an abstract model:

```
class ChronoModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(
        u"Create time",
        auto_now_add=True,
        db_index=True
    )
    modified = models.DateTimeField(
        u"Last change time",
        auto_now_add=True,
        db_index=True
    )

    class Meta(object):
        abstract = True
        ordering = ('-created', )
```

And I have several models inherited from ChronoModel. My problem is same for all of them - for example one of this models:

```
class BatchSession(ChronoModel):
    spent_seconds = models.BigIntegerField(
        u"spent_seconds", default=0, editable=False)
    max_seconds = models.BigIntegerField(
        u"max_seconds", null=True, blank=True)
    comment = models.CharField(
        u"comment", max_length=255, null=True, blank=False, 
unique=True)

    class Meta(ChronoModel.Meta):
        verbose_name = u'Session'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Sessions'
        ordering = ('-modified',)
        db_table = 'check_batchsession'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'#{}, {}/{} sec'.format(
            self.id, self.spent_seconds, self.max_seconds)
```

After creating and applying migration there is not index on fields "created" and "modified"

Command

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate app_name 0001 | grep INDEX
```

Shows me

```
BEGIN;
....
CREATE INDEX `check_batchsession_e2fa5388` ON `check_batchsession` (`created`);
CREATE INDEX `check_batchsession_9ae73c65` ON `check_batchsession` (`modified`);
....
COMMIT;
```

But mysql returns me:

```
mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM check_batchsession;
+--------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+
| Table              | Non_unique | Key_name                                         | Seq_in_index | Column_name |
+--------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+
| check_batchsession |          0 | PRIMARY                                          |            1 | id          |
| check_batchsession |          0 | check_batchsession_comment_558191ed0a395dfa_uniq |            1 | comment     |
+--------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

How can I resolve it?
Django 1.8.18
MySQL 5.6

Comment: Did you actually create and run the migrations for real?

Comment: You did `migrate` your database?

Comment: It was really old code. First migrations was made by south and I cant guarantee that migrate was successfully applied. I found my model in old commits:  " 'created': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'default': 'datetime.datetime.now', 'auto_now_add': 'True', 'db_index': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),  " and "'modified': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'default': 'datetime.datetime.now', 'auto_now': 'True', 'db_index': 'True', 'blank': 'True'})" in my model.

Comment: My new migrations was created by Django 1.7 and was faked. Can I recreate indexes on all my models?

Answer (score 0):

It was a Django South trouble.

I don't know what's happened, by all my indexes wasn't created. (If someone know - pleas write in comments)

My solution:

1) remove db_index=True from all fields in ChronoModel
2) makemigrations
3) migrate
3) add db_index=True to all all fields in ChronoModel
4) makemigrations
5) migrate

All my indexes was restored